# .NET Core Custom middleware does not catch services exceptions

Tags: asp.net, exception, .net-core

So I've just followed this tutorial:
https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/
Everything seemed to be working fine, but when it comes to services it does not handle any exception, and therefore it closes my app. It is no big deal when it's about debugging, but I need it to work at a real environment, and I want to catch every exception so it doesn't close the app.

StatusService.cs

```
public async void Add(List<Status> status) 
    {
        throw new Exception();
        await this.status.InsertManyAsync(status);
    }
```

StatusController.cs

```
 [HttpPost("add")]
    public IActionResult Add( [FromBody] List<Status> status)
    {
        if(status.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                statusService.Add(status);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        }
        return BadRequest("Array must not be empty");
    }
```

So if an Exception is thrown at StatusController it works perfectly fine, but when I call statusServices and the exception is thrown my app works.
Is there a workaround to make the exception be thrown at Controllers, or to make my middleware catch in every class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to catch all unhandled exceptions.

```
 public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
        public CustomExceptionFilterAttribute(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        }
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName);
            logger.LogError(context.Exception, "Action Error");
            var result = new ObjectResult(null)
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
            };
            context.Result = result;
        }
    }
```

Also don't rethrow exception in this way:

```
catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
```

because you lose part of errors stack trace. Just write

```
catch (Exception) { throw; }
```

Comment: I've tried but the problem is the same, if the exception is thrown within a controller it works fine, but inside another class the app crashes.

Comment: Then the problem lies elsewhere. Can you send the link to github repo of this project?